# Daemon not running on boot

Tags: 14.04, scripts, services

On an Ubuntu (14.04) VM, I have a simple node server that I want to run on startup. The following script works when invoked just as `./noderoot start`, but isn't running on startup. The script is

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: noderoot
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: bootin and rootin
# Description: Start root server on boot
### END INIT INFO
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/azureuser/npm/bin

case "$1" in
  start)
    forever --sourceDir=/var/www/root -p /var/www/logs app.js
  ;;
  stop)
    forever stop --sourceDir=/var/www/root app.js
  ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/noderoot {start|stop}"
    exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

This script lives inside `/etc/init.d` with `755` for the permissions. I have tried running `update-rc.d` with the following results:

```
root@linux-dev:~# update-rc.d noderoot defaults 80
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/noderoot ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
   /etc/rc1.d/K80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
   /etc/rc6.d/K80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
   /etc/rc2.d/S80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
   /etc/rc3.d/S80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
   /etc/rc4.d/S80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
   /etc/rc5.d/S80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
root@linux-dev:~# update-rc.d noderoot enable
update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match noderoot Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match noderoot Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
 Enabling system startup links for /etc/init.d/noderoot ...
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/noderoot ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K80noderoot
   /etc/rc1.d/K80noderoot
   /etc/rc2.d/S80noderoot
   /etc/rc3.d/S80noderoot
   /etc/rc4.d/S80noderoot
   /etc/rc5.d/S80noderoot
   /etc/rc6.d/K80noderoot
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/noderoot ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
   /etc/rc1.d/K80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
   /etc/rc6.d/K80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
   /etc/rc2.d/S80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
   /etc/rc3.d/S80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
   /etc/rc4.d/S80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
   /etc/rc5.d/S80noderoot -> ../init.d/noderoot
```

As far as I can tell, this completed successfully. I can start the service by running `sudo service noderoot start`. However, my executable isn't running when the machine reboots. Is there a way to troubleshoot what's going on? Any particular log file that may shed some light on how to fix this?

Comment: This can happen if there are errors that you can find in `/var/log/boot.log`. If you need help post it on http://pastebin.com/ and update your question with url.

Comment: @Letizia I found a relevant line in the log file: `/etc/rc2.d/S80noderoot: 16: /etc/rc2.d/S80noderoot: forever: not found`. It looks like the forever executable isn't being found.

Comment: Probably you should add `forever` path to `PATH` variable.

Comment: @Letizia I found it, I had the `PATH` and `NODE_PATH` variables reversed. Derp. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. If you want, you can write your own answer to help people with same problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the logs at `/var/log/boot.log` (location provided by Letizia), I found a very suspicious line:

```
/etc/rc2.d/S80noderoot: 16: /etc/rc2.d/S80noderoot: forever: not found
```

The command not being found pointed to it being a problem with the path. Sure enough, the lines

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/azureuser/npm/bin
```

were reversed. Switching these variables to point to the right directories, as well as adding a `cd` to the script before executing `forever` appears to have solved any issues the run script was having.